# Saving image into SQL Server with web service in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin.android

I am developing an app with Xamarin Android, I want to select an image from the gallery and save it to a SQL Server database using a WCF service.

My code is working except one part that the image want to convert and save into the database.

My column datatype for the image is: `varbinary(MAX)`.

My variable definition for the image in the project is: `byte[] imageByte;`

Some part of my code is below:

```
private void PicSelected()
{
        //mSelectedPic = selectedPic;
        Intent = new Intent();
        Intent.SetType("image/*");
        Intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
        StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(Intent, "Select Picture"),0);
}

protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
        {
            Stream stream = ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(data.Data);

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(stream);
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
            bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Webp, 100, memStream);
            byte[] picData = memStream.ToArray();
            picDataPublic = picData;
        }
}
```

This code selects a picture from the gallery and then convert it to byte array (`byte[]`), I think the problem is here.

Then the code shown below communicates with the database and passes the data to the WCF service.

```
_btnAdd.Click += async (sender, args) =>
        {
            string sUrl = "http://192.168.43.31/Service1.svc/insertIntoTableAdvertise";
            string sContentType = "application/json";
            CheckAppPermissions();

            JObject oJsonObject = new JObject();
            oJsonObject.Add("TxtGroup", _edtAdvGrouping.Text);
            oJsonObject.Add("TxtTitle", _edtTitle.Text);
            oJsonObject.Add("TxtDate", "1397/10/14");
            oJsonObject.Add("TxtLocation", "شاهین");
            oJsonObject.Add("TxtNumber", _edtNumber.Text);
            oJsonObject.Add("TxtPrice", _edtPrice.Text);
            oJsonObject.Add("TxtExpression", _edtExpression.Text);
            oJsonObject.Add("ImageByte", Convert.ToBase64String(picDataPublic));
            //oJsonObject.Add("ImageByte", "");

            try
            {
                var content = new StringContent(oJsonObject.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, sContentType);

                var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(sUrl, content);

                var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                if (responseContent == "1")
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Success. " + responseContent, ToastLength.Short).Show();

                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Failure." + responseContent, ToastLength.Short).Show();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, ex.Message.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
            finally
            {
                this.Finish();
            }
        };
```

When the code is:

```
oJsonObject.Add("ImageByte", "");
```

the service works and returns a success message, but when this condition:

```
oJsonObject.Add("ImageByte", Convert.ToBase64String(picDataPublic));
```

the service doesn't work.

I think the problem is with converting the image to the byte array.

Please help me with this problem

Comment: You really shouldn't be saving images to a database - use the filesystem instead as that's what it's designed for. Otrherwise you will see exponential growth in the database size and the db server will become congested. Store metadata regarding the file in the database.

Comment: @user1666620 Can you put your code for what you said about filesystem please?

Comment: google it, there are many tutorials available. if you have a problem by all means ask another question.

Comment: @user1666620 I googled it and i found that for saving an image to database you must convert it to byte array and i want to you this way

Comment: Why are you converting it to base64? Why not directly send byte[]

Comment: Based on your description, your issue was related to Converting bytes[] to VARBINARY is not working, you could refer to the following link.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45156682/converting-bytes-to-varbinary-is-not-working